# Why SQL doesn't see the table I created within a data set?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I created a data set `employee_data`. I loaded tables `departments` and `employee`. When I INNER JOIN the tables the error says `departments` should be qualified with a dataset.

[image: SQL Query]

Comment: note the difference between the table references in the `FROM` and `JOIN` elements

Comment: [mre] [ask] [Help] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: I do not see columns for name or role, I see an employee table that contains 2 columns departments, and employee. You cannot INNER JOIN on departments because it is a column, not a table. If those columns are already specified, we can not see them in this image.

Comment: Your edit did not act on my last comment. PS [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery allows you to `JOIN` tables from 2 different datasets as long as they belong on the same Data location. This means **BigQuery** will require you to include the **dataset name** on your `INNER JOIN`.

In addition, you must use aliases so that you can specify the aliases on your columns to be used on the query. You may try and use below query:

```sql
SELECT
employee.name AS employee_name,
employee.role AS employee_role,
deparments.name AS departments_name
FROM
`your-project-id.employee_data.employee` employee
INNER JOIN
`your-project-id.employee_data.departments` deparments ON
employee.department_id = departments.department_id;
```

Just update the `your-project-id` with your actual `project ID`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, no need for using aliases, just include dataset name and (.) table name in FROM, INNER JOIN and ON

```
SELECT 
employees.name as empName,
employees.role as empRole,
departments.name as depName
FROM
employee_data.employees
INNER JOIN employee_data.departments
ON employees.department_id=departments.department_id
```